# Mouse pointer moves automatically and interact with applications

Tags: windows-10, mouse-cursor

I have an acer laptop with windows 10(x64) (6gb/1tb)

#### The issue

> The mouse pointer sometimes move automatically, click some places, right click some places, drag some windows, close some windows and then stop.

I can't control it using touch pad. even if I tried to control it, it won't work.

I would like to get a solution because most of the time it close google chrome, where I have pending works/ typed contents

It happens rarely but suddenly from scratch. I mean it is unpredictable when it'll happen.

---

<sup>*I discussed about this with the mod Journeyman Geek in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6173172#6173172) and he advised me to post here.*</sup>

Comment: Do you use a keyboard or mouse that has Macro buttons/functionality, or have you ever used macro software on you computer? Are you sure your computer is not freezing and you're seeing delayed input? I would suggest scanning your computer with something like Malwarebytes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Confuzing. I always connected to internet and turned on auto updates in windows (10) as well as avira. Avira will scan automatically every day. So I can't see a problem with malware. I never used a macro software.